# Использовании функции, определенной в другом файле

Tags: android, java

Я вынес функцию:

```
public boolean hasInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null) {
        return false;
    }
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (NetworkInfo ni: netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) if (ni.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(this.toString(), "Wifi conncetion found");
            return true;
        }
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) if (ni.isConnected()) {
            Log.d(this.toString(), "Mobile connection found");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

- в отдельный java файл, как теперь ее использовать в других java файлах?

Comment: @dayMe, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java это делается с помощью [import](http://www.softzenware.com/java/08.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Просто так метод выносить нельзя. Необходимо обернуть его в класс.